# Angular NgPrime table get all the data where checkbox is not selected

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using NgPrime Table and I am practicing a School Application. I am working with Attendance Module and I will display all the Students list with a checkbox and they should tick who are present. So I triggered a Click Event on Checkboxes but **I am not getting Values where checkbox is not Selected**.

```
          <ng-template pTemplate="body"
              let-student
              let-i="rowIndex"
              >
              <tr [pSelectableRow]="student">
                  <td >{{i+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{student.regnum}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <p-checkbox name="groupname" value="val1" (click)="attendance($event, student)"></p-checkbox>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </ng-template>
```

**TS Code:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    //Get students data on page load
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/student/studentslist').subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.json();
      this.student = data;
    });

    // For ngprime column names
    this.cols = [
      { field: 'S.No', header: 'S.No' },
      { field: 'regnum', header: 'Regnum' },
      { field: 'attendance', header: 'Attendance' }
  ];
  }

  //Save student regnums who are present
  attendance(checkbox, student) {
    if(checkbox.srcElement.checked) {
      this.checkedstudents.push(student.regnum);
    }
    else {
      this.removeStudent(student.regnum);
    }
  }

  //Remove Students who are clicked after unselecting the checkbox
  removeStudent(regnum){
    this.checkedstudents.forEach((item, index) => {
      if(item === regnum) this.checkedstudents.splice(index,1);
    });
 }
```

As you can see in above code I am just triggering an event on value change of checkboxes so I can get data of only Students present. Just give me some answer to find Students who are absent**(Checkbox with no Tick)**

[image]

**Solution1:**
I can just try in this way but I dont prefer:

On page load I can save all regnum present in an array and when some checkbox is checked I can take it's regnum value and splice it from the previous array. I know it's a long process and foolish kind of thing and I also want to get all the data on Submit Click in ngprime table(which is easy and helps me to learn about handling data in tables)

**Solution2: I Tried**

```
<ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-student>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" style="width: 50%;"
          class="btn btn-2 btn-2g" (click)="submitattendance(student)">Submit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
```

**TS file**

```
submitattendance(student) {
   console.log(student);
 }
```

But console is showing just my Model I created for Student and not the data

*Thanks in Advance, Happy Coding*

Comment: Share your ts code.

Comment: Updated my code @SunilSingh

Comment: Put the logs for variable `checkbox` and `student` inside `attendance` function. What is the value you see ?

Comment: I generally get the student regnum and whether checkbox is checked or not (true or false). If checkbox value is true I push the regnum into some array as he is present

Comment: Then rest of the things are looking fine. Are you getting any error ? What is the exact issue here ?

Comment: Here I am getting the regnum of students only who are present because I triggered event only on change so I cant get students data who are absent. Can we run a loop for all the data at the final Submit click and separate data into two array absent and present based on Checkbox????

Answer (score 0):

If you have any property ex `checked` ( or you can use new one ) in `student` object to bind with checkbox then you can bind through `ngModel` and get the list of all students whose property is checked.

```
<p-checkbox name="groupname" [(ngModel)]="student.checked"></p-checkbox>
```

No need to have `click` event.

Comment: I already did that by creating a model export class Attendance {
    constructor(public regnum:string, public attendance: string){}
} but I am getting failed in Submit Click where I want to return the whole Student data to my ts file.. CHeck my solution2 bruh I edited my post

Comment: You don't need to do anything. No need to create the separate model. It will add one more property called `checked`.

Comment: But I am getting this in Console bruh (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {field: "S.No", header: "S.No"}1: {field: "regnum", header: "Regnum"}2: {field: "attendance", header: "Attendance"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0) not the data . May be something wrong in what I am writing in footer

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
field: "S.No"
header: "S.No"
__proto__: Object
1:
field: "regnum"
header: "Regnum"
__proto__: Object
2:
field: "attendance"
header: "Attendance"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0) Its just showing my this.cols from .ts file bruh

Comment: print log for each student then share.

Comment: Bruh thats my problem bruh I dont have any idea to print data present in Table thats the reason I used click event which makes my code very huge now :(